# How do I create a report that displays Contacts created in the last (say) 30 days?

Tags: civireport, searchkit

This question was asked in October 2020. The answer was to use Drupal or Data Processor. We're using WordPress and we don't have the expertise to use Data Porcessor. Have there been any work-arounds developed in the past 18 months?
I tried creating a Smart Group but the filters for Created Date asks for fixed dates, not relative dates.

CiviCRM 5.45.0 on WordPress 5.9.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of things like this can now be done with SearchKit.  If you were searching for those who had died in the last 30 days, you could use [this](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/search#/create/Contact?params=%7B%22version%22:4,%22select%22:%5B%22id%22,%22display_name%22%5D,%22orderBy%22:%7B%7D,%22where%22:%5B%5B%22deceased_date%22,%22%3D%22,%22ending_30.day%22%5D%5D,%22groupBy%22:%5B%5D,%22join%22:%5B%5D,%22having%22:%5B%5D%7D)

But if you switch to 'Created Date' you don't get the same options.

The `birth_date` and `deceased_date` fields are of the `date` type but `created_date` and `modified_date` are of type `timestamp` which are handled differently.

There has been a lot of focus recently on dates vs timestamps so I'd suggest creating an issue [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues?scope=all&state=opened&search=searchkit) requesting that timestamps can be searched with date ranges as dates are.

Comment: Thanks for the explainer Aidan.

Comment: This bug in SearchKit is now fixed for v5.50: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23335